# About the colors in android

Tags: android, colors

I try to get the string value of a pixel color.
but when i run my app in different devices i get different values.
my code is here:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.firstfinger);
String v = String.valueOf(bit.getPixel(1640 , 10));
et.setText(v);
```

in one device i got : -15000554

in the other : -5867685

How should i do?
Or is there any other way to get the color of a pixel?

Comment: Did the devices have different resolutions?

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

The color at a particular position might be different from one device to another based on screen resolution

Comment: To extend on this, an example. Let's say you have a view that has a 50dp margin that is black, and a center of white. On a screen that is 720x480, the pixel color at (720, 480) is going to be black (bottom right edge of the screen), however on a screen with a resolution of 1280x720 the pixel (720, 480) is going to be closer to the center of the screen, in the white region of the screen.